# What is the term to make one matrix from two or more?

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology

I am looking for the proper term for the operation of creating one block matrix from two or more for example $[AB]$ from $A$, $B$. And what is the correct notation to denote such a matrix. Do we use a mid line as $[A\mid B]$ or just $[AB]$ or something else?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, a midline, if you mean block matrices. Also common is the Kronecker product $A\otimes B$.

Comment: There are many ways. There are block matrix constructions, Kronecker products, etc. It all depends on what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct notation is using a mid-line as you have demonstrated, and it is called **augmenting** matrices, or **matrix augmentation**.

Comment: Thank you, could you pls tell me the latex symbol if I put them one on top of other. (not side by side \mid)

Answer (score 1):

There are several operations to produce one matrix from two or more. What you probably want, is to build block matrices (matrix augmentation). Another possibility is the Kronnecker product of $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A\otimes B$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product. This has been generalized to the semi-tensor product of matrices, see www.iss.ac.cn/iss/iss_talk/iss2011chendaizhan.pdf‎.